# Loop through JavaScript Object and sub Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to loop through the response of an API.
My code so far:

```
async function getStreams(gamename){ 
  let url = `https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/?game=${gamename}`;
  const response = await fetch(url,{ method: 'GET', headers: headers});
  const json =  await response.json();
  var test = Object.values(json)
});
```

the test variable returns an object like [this](https://hastebin.com/uhipumagur.json).

the raw response looks like [this](https://hastebin.com/sixodamobe.json).

Since everything I'm interested in is under `streams` I'm not sure how to separate each stream and then check every aspect such as the `channels.language` key.

I felt like I almost had it with the following:

```
Object.values(json).forEach(function(key,index) {
// key: the name of the object key
// index: the ordinal position of the key within the object 
  console.log(key)
});
```

However, now I need to go deeper into the key—`key.values`, `key[0]`, and anything like that won't work. I need to loop through everything of this specified key and check if `language === 'de'`, then print the whole key/object. Since the `language` tag is in another sub-object `channel` within it, I'm confused about what to use.

Comment: Can you post the response, then what you want to do with it. Links to data are no good because if the link dies, the question becomes pointless

Comment: Gunman, Ben Bright wrote a utility for this check it out on https://gist.github.com/iambenbright/9573c844025f65cd82ce8e3e36897a9e

Comment: @DarrenSweeney the response was quite long thats why i decided to post it on a text bin. This is the raw response from the api https://hastebin.com/sixodamobe.json

Comment: @Rilla i added it and i am confused on how it works, ive 
var test = Object(response.json());
propPicker(test,["channel"] /... tried around and it always returns {}

Comment: okay i would make a quick guide on how to use it in the answers. Please check it out

Comment: @Rilla alright could you link me it when finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to use the Prop Filter Utility::

```js
let toString = Object.prototype.toString;

// strict object check
function isObject(value) {
  return toString.call(value) === '[object Object]';
}

// strict array check
function isArray(value) {
  return toString.call(value) === '[object Array]';
}

function propPicker(data = {}, props = []) {
  // type guard for props parameter
  // ensure it is an array
  if (!isArray(props)) {
    throw new TypeError('Second parameter must be an array');
  }

  // type guard for data parameter
  // ensure it is an object
  if (!isObject(data)) {
    throw new TypeError('first parameter must be an object');
  }

  // the object or result to return
  let output = {};

  // iterate through data
  // to pick properties
  Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    // add key (property) to the result to be
    // returned if it is present on the
    // data object
    if (props.includes(key)) {
      output[key] = data[key];
    }

    // recursive traverse the key (property)
    // if it is an object
    else if (isObject(data[key])) {
      let selectedProps = propPicker(data[key], props);
      let obj;

      // add keys (properties) from nested object
      // if the key is present on the data object
      if (Object.keys(selectedProps).length) {
        obj = {
          [key]: selectedProps,
        };
      }

      // merge main object and keys with
      // nested objects with filtered keys
      output = Object.assign({}, output, obj);
    }
  });

  return output;
}



const streamsObject = {
    "streams": [
        {
            "_id": 209427714,
            "game": "VALORANT",
            "broadcast_platform": "live",
            "community_id": "",
            "community_ids": [],
            "viewers": 18874,
            "video_height": 1080,
            "average_fps": 60,
            "delay": 0,
            "created_at": "2020-08-01T13:30:04Z",
            "is_playlist": false,
            "stream_type": "live",
            "preview": {
                "small": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_mandatory-80x45.jpg",
                "medium": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_mandatory-320x180.jpg",
                "large": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_mandatory-640x360.jpg",
                "template": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_mandatory-{width}x{height}.jpg"
            },
            "channel": {
                "mature": false,
                "status": "IGNITION SERIES x MANDATORY.GG CUP - DAY 2 - QUARTER FINALS - NiP 1 - 1 Those Guys",
                "broadcaster_language": "en",
                "broadcaster_software": "",
                "display_name": "Mandatory",
                "game": "VALORANT",
                "language": "fr",
                "_id": 514026431,
                "name": "mandatory",
                "created_at": "2020-04-14T13:33:08.208742Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-08-01T16:33:34.993381Z",
                "partner": true,
                "logo": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/ffd17c21-5333-4817-8376-0c0df97e97bb-profile_image-300x300.png",
                "video_banner": null,
                "profile_banner": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/762a158e-4cc9-40a5-9fbd-a3d1bfbb4360-profile_banner-480.png",
                "profile_banner_background_color": "",
                "url": "https://www.twitch.tv/mandatory",
                "views": 158550,
                "followers": 8280,
                "broadcaster_type": "",
                "description": "Welcome on Mandatory.GG official Twitch channel ! We're a 100% Valorant community.",
                "private_video": false,
                "privacy_options_enabled": false
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": 209051778,
            "game": "VALORANT",
            "broadcast_platform": "live",
            "community_id": "",
            "community_ids": [],
            "viewers": 15453,
            "video_height": 1080,
            "average_fps": 60,
            "delay": 0,
            "created_at": "2020-08-01T12:48:03Z",
            "is_playlist": false,
            "stream_type": "live",
            "preview": {
                "small": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_zerator-80x45.jpg",
                "medium": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_zerator-320x180.jpg",
                "large": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_zerator-640x360.jpg",
                "template": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_zerator-{width}x{height}.jpg"
            },
            "channel": {
                "mature": true,
                "status": "IGNITION SERIES x MANDATORY.GG CUP - DEMI-FINALE #1 [BO3] - G2 ESPORTS 0 - 0 BBL ESPORTS",
                "broadcaster_language": "fr",
                "broadcaster_software": "",
                "display_name": "ZeratoR",
                "game": "VALORANT",
                "language": "fr",
                "_id": 41719107,
                "name": "zerator",
                "created_at": "2013-03-25T23:44:28.227952Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-08-01T16:29:35.684905Z",
                "partner": true,
                "logo": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/599b546a-c27f-4684-93ff-5eeecd01fb2b-profile_image-300x300.png",
                "video_banner": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/ea5ccb61-1bc8-44bd-9840-4f24489b3126-channel_offline_image-1920x1080.jpeg",
                "profile_banner": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/77e1f053-e6f9-4b90-8872-b0935a43ad3c-profile_banner-480.jpeg",
                "profile_banner_background_color": "",
                "url": "https://www.twitch.tv/zerator",
                "views": 92693955,
                "followers": 875927,
                "broadcaster_type": "",
                "description": "French Independent Streamer // contact : @tpdach on twitter or dach@zerator.tv",
                "private_video": false,
                "privacy_options_enabled": false
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": 2360043473,
            "game": "VALORANT",
            "broadcast_platform": "live",
            "community_id": "",
            "community_ids": [],
            "viewers": 3043,
            "video_height": 1080,
            "average_fps": 60,
            "delay": 0,
            "created_at": "2020-08-01T09:19:04Z",
            "is_playlist": false,
            "stream_type": "live",
            "preview": {
                "small": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_hastad-80x45.jpg",
                "medium": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_hastad-320x180.jpg",
                "large": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_hastad-640x360.jpg",
                "template": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_hastad-{width}x{height}.jpg"
            },
            "channel": {
                "mature": false,
                "status": "HASTAD - RADIANTE - i love you hachi s2",
                "broadcaster_language": "pt",
                "broadcaster_software": "",
                "display_name": "hastad",
                "game": "VALORANT",
                "language": "pt-br",
                "_id": 26857029,
                "name": "hastad",
                "created_at": "2011-12-18T00:05:08.641512Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-08-01T16:30:04.644868Z",
                "partner": true,
                "logo": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/6b23888a-0500-49ec-99fa-4e89c721f3bc-profile_image-300x300.png",
                "video_banner": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/646ab44cadea492b-channel_offline_image-1920x1080.png",
                "profile_banner": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/a6f2ef1d-1e37-481c-838a-7f18c53d1c16-profile_banner-480.png",
                "profile_banner_background_color": "",
                "url": "https://www.twitch.tv/hastad",
                "views": 45423892,
                "followers": 848327,
                "broadcaster_type": "",
                "description": "hastad - RADIANT - VALORANT PLAYER - RAZE IS MY MAINLIVES TODOS OS DIAS 9AM ATÉ 9PM",
                "private_video": false,
                "privacy_options_enabled": false
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": 2360274689,
            "game": "VALORANT",
            "broadcast_platform": "live",
            "community_id": "",
            "community_ids": [],
            "viewers": 1607,
            "video_height": 1080,
            "average_fps": 60,
            "delay": 0,
            "created_at": "2020-08-01T13:10:26Z",
            "is_playlist": false,
            "stream_type": "live",
            "preview": {
                "small": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_sacy-80x45.jpg",
                "medium": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_sacy-320x180.jpg",
                "large": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_sacy-640x360.jpg",
                "template": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_sacy-{width}x{height}.jpg"
            },
            "channel": {
                "mature": false,
                "status": "SACY - RANKED RADIANTE - !loja !youtube",
                "broadcaster_language": "pt",
                "broadcaster_software": "",
                "display_name": "sacy",
                "game": "VALORANT",
                "language": "pt-br",
                "_id": 25116812,
                "name": "sacy",
                "created_at": "2011-09-27T23:29:45.144335Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-08-01T16:29:55.624657Z",
                "partner": true,
                "logo": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/33aaee2d-750b-4020-94b1-6f2633d86c41-profile_image-300x300.png",
                "video_banner": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/bf58561f-707d-48a6-a23c-8af0c4b2b0f3-channel_offline_image-1920x1080.png",
                "profile_banner": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/779f4cbf-4dd6-4f2e-9c5a-d754dc42469c-profile_banner-480.png",
                "profile_banner_background_color": "",
                "url": "https://www.twitch.tv/sacy",
                "views": 5775708,
                "followers": 199173,
                "broadcaster_type": "",
                "description": "",
                "private_video": false,
                "privacy_options_enabled": false
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": 210846322,
            "game": "VALORANT",
            "broadcast_platform": "live",
            "community_id": "",
            "community_ids": [],
            "viewers": 1533,
            "video_height": 1080,
            "average_fps": 60,
            "delay": 0,
            "created_at": "2020-08-01T16:08:33Z",
            "is_playlist": false,
            "stream_type": "live",
            "preview": {
                "small": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_blackelespanolito-80x45.jpg",
                "medium": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_blackelespanolito-320x180.jpg",
                "large": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_blackelespanolito-640x360.jpg",
                "template": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_blackelespanolito-{width}x{height}.jpg"
            },
            "channel": {
                "mature": false,
                "status": "SUBIENDO A INMORTAL ANTES DE QUE ACABE EL ACTO | 3 DIAS",
                "broadcaster_language": "es",
                "broadcaster_software": "",
                "display_name": "blackelespanolito",
                "game": "VALORANT",
                "language": "es",
                "_id": 68124914,
                "name": "blackelespanolito",
                "created_at": "2014-08-04T04:27:31.572115Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-08-01T16:29:52.636507Z",
                "partner": true,
                "logo": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/22543fff-bfc5-4133-bfd3-75557a5e35ce-profile_image-300x300.png",
                "video_banner": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/d5fb2d77-1d31-43f6-8b51-0c98ec5b5c8f-channel_offline_image-1920x1080.png",
                "profile_banner": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/574995b0-4ada-4329-92bb-db5a9ef9e924-profile_banner-480.png",
                "profile_banner_background_color": "",
                "url": "https://www.twitch.tv/blackelespanolito",
                "views": 9858458,
                "followers": 309222,
                "broadcaster_type": "",
                "description": "CS:GO Y VALORANT 24/7",
                "private_video": false,
                "privacy_options_enabled": false
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": 3921422817798718623,
            "game": "VALORANT",
            "broadcast_platform": "live",
            "community_id": "",
            "community_ids": [],
            "viewers": 1454,
            "video_height": 1080,
            "average_fps": 60,
            "delay": 0,
            "created_at": "2020-08-01T13:34:45Z",
            "is_playlist": false,
            "stream_type": "live",
            "preview": {
                "small": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_jasonr-80x45.jpg",
                "medium": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_jasonr-320x180.jpg",
                "large": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_jasonr-640x360.jpg",
                "template": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_jasonr-{width}x{height}.jpg"
            },
            "channel": {
                "mature": false,
                "status": "100T VS BBG",
                "broadcaster_language": "en",
                "broadcaster_software": "",
                "display_name": "JASONR",
                "game": "VALORANT",
                "language": "en",
                "_id": 103262684,
                "name": "jasonr",
                "created_at": "2015-09-29T06:06:05.814442Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-08-01T16:49:15.189364Z",
                "partner": true,
                "logo": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/4a5c1148-a148-4849-a2a8-656dc73d52ea-profile_image-300x300.png",
                "video_banner": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/22d82e7e-0531-4790-897d-6e2078cf95e6-channel_offline_image-1920x1080.png",
                "profile_banner": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/7f04e0b5-7e59-4c29-90cc-847db3dbedfc-profile_banner-480.png",
                "profile_banner_background_color": "",
                "url": "https://www.twitch.tv/jasonr",
                "views": 36354582,
                "followers": 772580,
                "broadcaster_type": "",
                "description": "bangin",
                "private_video": false,
                "privacy_options_enabled": false
            }
        }
    ]
}


streamsObject.streams.forEach(stream => {
  let channelObj = propPicker(stream, ["language"])
  if (channelObj.channel && channelObj.channel.language && channelObj.channel.language == "fr") {
  console.log(stream)
}
})
```

Comment: i had to reduce the the dataset to so the code doesn't get messy

Answer (score 0):

Break down the problem. `streams` is an array of objects. You can filter them based on language prop from the `channel`.

```
const germanChannels = streams.filter(stream => stream.channel.language === 'de');
```

Comment: i tried something like that but it keeps saying ``TypeError: Cannot read property 'language' of undefined``

Answer (score 0):

`Object.values` gives you the *values*, *not* the keys (that would be `Object.keys`; make sense?)—if the value is an object, you'll get that object in the first parameter. Thus, if you want to print the object if `channel.language === 'de'` from that stream object, it's as simple as the following:

```js
Object.streams.values(json).forEach(function (value) {
  // value: the **value** of the object key
  if (value.channel.language === 'de') console.log(value);
});
```

(Additionally you are wanting to iterate over the `streams` property, not the JSON itself.)

Comment: also gives me ``TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined`` also did it with if(value.channel.language btw^^

Comment: Oh, oops, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's quick solution :

```
Object.keys(jsonData).forEach(function(key) {
    var values = jsonData[key];
    values.forEach(obj => {
      console.log(obj.channel.language);
      if(obj.channel.language === 'de') {
      // apply custom logic or in-depth filters here
      console.log(obj); 
      }
    })
});
```